# Get latest from array of microtimes

Tags: php, datetime, microtime

I am looping through a list of files and grabbing their modified date, which is returned in microtime format:

```
int(1633986072)
int(1633971686)
int(1634014866)
int(1634000474)
```

I can loop through these, but unsure which function is best to identify which is the latest.

Is `strtotime` best method here or maybe any other alternatives?

Comment: These are probably timestamps. The highest value is what you are looking for. When the values are all in an array, you can use the max function.
$latestTimestamp = max([1633986072,1633971686,1634014866,1634000474]); To get a readable date you can use date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions like [filemtime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) return the time as a Unix timestamp. The time stamps can be collected in an array.

```
$timeStamps = [
  1633986072,
  1633971686,
  1634014866,
  1634000474
];
```

You get the last value with the [max](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) function.

```
$lastTs = max($timeStamps);  //1634014866
```

With the [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date) function, you can display the timestamp as human-readable local time. Example for time zone Europe/Berlin:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$lastTs);  //2021-10-12 07:01:06
```

Edit: To the additional question how can I return the two highest values?

For this, [rsort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) is used to sort the timestamps in descending order. The highest value, the second highest, etc. can then easily be accessed via index as long as there are values in the array.

```
rsort($timeStamps);
$lastTs = $timeStamps[0];  //1634014866
$last2Ts = $timeStamps[1]; //1634000474
```

Comment: Hi @jspit - do you know a good method to return the two highest values?

Comment: @wharfdale I have expanded my answer.